# Client not receiving Server Sent Events from Express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-sent-events

I have a Next.js (React) client that I've setup to listen to Server-Sent Events from my Node.js/Express.js server, but it doesn't seem to be receiving messages for some reason.

The `open` and `error` events of `EventSource` are working properly, but whenever I use `.onmessage` it doesn't detect anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Express.js Code:

```js
router.get('/stream/:walletAddress', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.set({
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        });
        res.flushHeaders();

        let x = 0;
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            res.write(`event: message\n`);
            res.write(`data: ${x++}\n\n`);
        }, 2000);

        res.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Client closed.');
            clearInterval(id);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Next.js (React) Code:

```js
import { API_URL } from 'config';
import { useWalletStore } from 'src/stores';


export const FetchTxsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const safeSdkReader = useWalletStore(state => state.safeSdkReader);

    useEffect(() => {
        const eventSource = new EventSource(
            `${API_URL}/transactions/stream/${safeSdkReader.getAddress()}`
        );

        eventSource.onopen = function (e) {
            console.log('Successfully connected.');
        };

        eventSource.onerror = function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            eventSource.close();
        };

        // ! Should fire here but doesn't!
        eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log('Event: ', event);
        };

        return () => {
            console.log('Connection closed.');
            eventSource.close();
        };
    }, [safeSdkReader]);

    return <>{children}</>
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know why, but the headers were missing `'Content-Encoding': 'none'`.

```js
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',          
  'Content-Encoding': 'none',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
```

Comment: A lot of time spent. And this was the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian D. `'Content-Encoding': 'none'` was indeed the missing part

Comment: I randomly ran into this as well after our SSE endpoint suddenly was broken. If someone knows why, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times dealing with pub/sub systems, the subscriber or consumer can connect to the broker which can fire all of the events of starting, but getting no messages. Are you sure you’re connected to the right destination?

The Next.js is looking for `/transactions/stream/...` where Express.js looks like it might be pointing to just the resource `/stream/...`. Is that expected?

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. yes, since I'm exporting the router and using it in `app.use()` the correct path is actually `/transactions/stream/...`